# 06 dodge dakota melted a ignition coil now getting pcm codes an truck wont start but sounds like it wants to

Tags: electronic-control-module

[image] I melted a ignition coil now I'm getting pcm codes truck wont start but tries it's best

Comment: Did you determine WHY the ign. coil melted?  Also, what specific codes are you getting?  You've not really provided anywhere near enough information for anyone here to provide much help.

Answer (score 0):

The coil/plug goes bad and then overheats the drivers in the pcm. When the drivers overheat they fail either open or shorted. If failed shorted then you get melted coil packs.

You need to send out your ecu for repair or replace it.